# При открытии активности с фрагментом Google карт, она немедленно закрывается

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Реализовал по [примеру](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/).

Сразу же после открытия активности, с фрагментом *Google* карт, она немедленно закрывается. В логах кидает такой Warning:

> 16034-16034 D/dalvikvm: open_cached_dex_file : /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/chimera-module-root/module-ca8b2a9144773fc3650c54ed299f2d4558171b12/MapsModule.apk /data/dalvik-cache/data@data@com.google.android.gms@app_chimera@chimera-module-root@module-ca8b2a9144773fc3650c54ed299f2d4558171b12@MapsModule.apk@classes.dex
>   16034-16034 D/ChimeraFileApk: Classloading successful, but code may not be optimized. It will either run in fallback (interpreted mode) or the odex has been found and isDexOptNeeded is misreporting a failure.
>   16034-16034 I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 8298000
>   16034-16034 I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 8489036
>   16034-16034 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.mw.a
>   19859-20049 A/libc: @@@ ABORTING: LIBC: ARGUMENT IS INVALID HEAP ADDRESS IN dlfree addr=0x5fdc2940
>   19859-20049 A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 20049 (Thread-770)
>   19859-20025 D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x62d27948 sslRead buf=0x42263bd0 len=1,timeo=2500

Погуглил, добавил *Multidex*, в соответствии с [ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31342684/getting-error-could-not-find-class-android-app-appopsmanager-referenced-from), но не помогло.

Вот манифест:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="mypakcagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="mypakcagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<permission
    android:name="mypakcagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<permission
    android:name="mypakcagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.AuthenticationActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Auth"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".receivers.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".receivers.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/maps_api_key" />

</application>
```

public class MapPane extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А можете показать манифест?

Comment: @hexonxons, обновил.

Comment: эта ошибка означает, что далвик не может найти класс `AppOpsManager`. Этот класс появился с API 19, соответственно при запуске на android < 4.4 его и не будет. Но в коде самой библиотеки он есть. Возможно установлен неправильный `targetSdkVersion`, попробуйте поставить его как 23.

Comment: @hexonxons дело в том, что у меня стоит 23. Но я запускаю его на девайсе с 4.2. То что получается, что карты не будут работать на  моем девайсе?

Comment: По идее должны. А стектрейс падения можно ещё?

Comment: @hexonxons, обновил.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема не в `E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.mw.a`,на эти сообщения скорее всего не надо обращать внимание.

Падение происходит по следующей причине:

```
A/libc: @@@ ABORTING: LIBC: ARGUMENT IS INVALID HEAP ADDRESS IN dlfree addr=0x5fdc2940
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 20049 (Thread-770)
```

Гугл говорит, что это может быть связано с некорректной реализацией многопоточности приложения - один из вариантов есть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662446/invalid-heap-address-and-fatal-signal-11), но чтобы выяснить что конкретно - надо смотреть сам код.

Comment: Проблема в том, что код достаточно простой. Не работает на одном девайсе, но работает на другом... Добавил код. Ничего мощного я не делаю там, просто показываю карту.

Comment: @Alexander, Попробуйте использовать play-services-gcm версии 8.4.0 и обновить все используемые либы до последней версии. Возможно проблема в самом устройстве, или эмуляторе, если используется он. [Вот один из вариантов.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552310/fatal-signal-11-when-loading-mapfragment-from-google-play-services), [возможная проблема в system image API17](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416142/unexpected-value-from-nativegetenabledtags-0), от 12 года, но может быть актуальна. Проверьте еще, что время на устройстве выставлено актуальное.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас в проекте больше использьуется больше 65к методов. В градле сотрите строчку которая портирует google play services и импортните только то, что нужно на самом деле. Например  compile `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'`

Comment: К сожаленю нет. Вот как я подключил сервисы:     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'. Если бы в проекте было больше 56к методов, разве я сбилдил бы приложение?

Comment: Да, тогда бы не скомпилировалось вообще